# sprintf update with amount with value from input text box

Tags: php, mysql

if i have

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE stuffntory SET `youwho`=%s, stock=stock -1, list=%s WHERE something=%s",
```

instead of minus -1 I would like to have -Quanity that was input by text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `sprintf()` format to have a placeholder for *quantity*. Assuming *quantity* is an integer:

```
sprintf("UPDATE stuffntory SET `youwho`=%s, stock=stock - %d, list=%s WHERE something=%s", ...)
```

Comment: Sorry I mean I would just have to make the input type box a integer right? nothing else? no other changes? thanks to by the way

Comment: Yes. But you should never trust user input. I encourage you to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).